# I'm weirdly blocked on Meta

Tags: support, bug

I'm [yyyyyyyan](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/225749/yyyyyyyan) and this is not my primary account. I created this account so I could post this here, because I couldn't figure out what to do.

A few days ago I tried to ask a question about email spoofing on Information Security Exchange. The question had some URIs and email addresses in it, and maybe because of this it was marked as spam and I couldn't post it. I went to Meta to try to ask for help and surprisingly Meta simply wouldn't load for me.

If I try to access any page under `security.meta.stackexchange.com` I get back an empty page and a 500 HTTP error code. If I logout or try to access with this account, it works out perfectly. I'm not sure if my post being marked as spam resulted in this, but what about now, how can I fix it?

As I said, it's been days, but I'm still getting this error. And the worst part is I have nothing I can do, since there's no other clear way of getting in contact with someone who could help me with this. I had to create another account and post a bad answer to get enough reputation to post this.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the email spoofing question:

It seems you've burned a fresh account. I mean, no harm done. You've posted a *total* of four posts, that's three questions and one answer, on all of stackexchange.

So, by all means, just make a new account, and avoid doing what you did to get your first post classified as spam so quickly.